# SQL - Select two different values based on the same condition

Tags: sql, case-statement

Is it possible in SQL to have a case statement that selects two different values based on the same condition?

For example, if I had a table called Person with the following columns:

- Name
- Age
- EyeColor

So if the person is 18 years old or older, I want to select their name. But if they are less than 18, I want to select their eye color. How can I do this using a case statement?

**Sample Data:**

```
NAME    AGE    EyeColor
------  -----  --------
John    17     Brown
Mike    21     Blue
Peter   16     Green
Alan    18     Brown
```

**Expected result:**

```
NameOrEyeColor
--------------
Brown
Mike
Green
Alan
```

Comment: Please try something, tell us what you tried, and tell us what didn't work.

Comment: Please update your question tags with the specific flavor of SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both columns are the same data type, then:

```
select
  case
    when age >= 18 then name
    else eyecolor
  end as columnname
from person
```

although in a Mysql database this would work for columns with different data types because of the implicit conversion done (check [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)).

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
SELECT CASE WHEN age = 18 THEN name 
WHEN age < 18 THEN eyeColor END AS mySelection
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply use a `CASE STATEMENT`for each condition:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Age = 18 THEN Name END) AS Name, (CASE WHEN Age < 18 THEN EyeColour END) AS EyeColour
FROM Person
```

Or, perhaps you're looking for:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Age = 18 THEN Name WHEN Age < 18 THEN EyeColour END) as Condition
FROM Person
```

Although that last option would give you results that are not clear.  What if the person's name is `Blue` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF statement in select

For example

```
SELECT
IF(Age > 18, Name, EyeColor) as val
FROM table
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html